# Having issues when printing an array of chars?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management, malloc

Since I don't really understand the overall issue I am having, it's become very difficult to debug.

```
char *o_key_pad = (char*)malloc(SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
for(int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
    o_key_pad[i] = 'a';
}
printf("%s\n", o_key_pad);

char *i_key_pad = (char*)malloc(SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
for(int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
    i_key_pad[i] = 'b';
}

printf("%s\n", o_key_pad);
printf("%s\n", i_key_pad);
```

And i obtain outputs:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Why does the array 'o_key_pad' get extended to include whatever i put in array 'i_key_pad', seems like some sort of memory issue?

Note: I understand that it can be done more effectively but to show my point more clearly I have laid it out like this.

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't) cast the return value of `malloc`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1701799).

Comment: `sizeof char == 1`, `sizeof` returns size of its value in ... chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` doesn't know where to stop unless you properly null-terminate your strings. C-style strings are as follows (the following two lines are equivalent; writing a string in quotes [a "string literal"] automatically creates a null-terminated character array):

```
char str[] = "hello world";
char str2[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\0' };
```

This is what your code should look like:

```
int i;
char *o_key_pad = malloc(SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH * sizeof (char) + 1);
for (i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
    o_key_pad[i] = 'a';
}
o_key_pad[i] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", o_key_pad);

char *i_key_pad = malloc(SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH * sizeof (char) + 1);
for (i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
    i_key_pad[i] = 'b';
}
i_key_pad[i] = '\0';

printf("%s\n", o_key_pad);
printf("%s\n", i_key_pad);

/* Don't forget to free when done. */
free(o_key_pad);
free(i_key pad);
```

Comment: Your code exhibits undefined behavior too. You write the null character beyond the end of the allocated space.

Comment: Also note that technically `char *str3 = "hello world"; ` is slightly different than `str` and `str2` because in this case the array will not be modifiable, it will be placed in the read-only section.

Answer (score 2):

You have `char` arrays, but they do not have room for a string terminator, and in fact you do not append one.  The contents are not, therefore, proper C strings.  When you lie to `printf()` about that, anything can happen, but in practice, printing beyond the intended bounds of your data is a likely outcome.

If you do not want to add a terminator, then you could put a maximum field width into your format:

```
printf("%.32s\n", o_key_pad);
```

, or alternatively

```
printf("%.*s\n", SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH, o_key_pad);
```

if you don't want to hardcode the field width directly into the format.

Answer (score 1):

Your strings are not NULL-terminated, resulting in undefined behavior when passed to `printf`. You could either allocate one more byte and add a NULL character, or specify a maximum field width for your string.